# load XML file to QTP

Tags: qtp

May I request you to help me in clarifying a query..

I am getting an error message "80004005- file could not be opened"

The scenario is I am trying to load an XML file created using VB script at run time. ie the creation of the XML and loading it in to QTP are handled in the same script one after the other. 
I am able to load files which was created earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I got it resolved. The reason wass that the object was not closed after it is being created.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for attempting to communicate the final solution, and being polite even though nobody gave it a try.